# When using @KafkaListener in springboot, how to set idleBetweenPolls

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

"idleBetweenPolls" is a handy config in spring-kafka, to adjust the rate of consumption.

However when checking source code and doc of springboot, there seems to be no mention of this props or how to propagate some particular value into org.springframework.kafka.listener.ContainerProperties.

Anyone know of anyway to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property was missing in spring-boot at the time. Hence did not get propagated to kafka. It was then added
https://github.com/Cwikius-Spring/spring-boot/commit/1b8bfaa1fb6af40750cbd8030d0f01f137e7f80e

Answer (score 0):

Add a container factory customizer bean:

```java
@Component
class Customizer {

    public Customizer(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> factory) {
        factory.getContainerProperties().setIdleBetweenPolls(5_000L);
    }

}
```

This will set it on all containers.

If you only want to set it on a specific container:

```java
@Component
class Customizer2 {

    public Customizer2(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> factory) {
        factory.setContainerCustomizer(container -> {
            if (container.getContainerProperties().getGroupId().equals("theOneIWant") {
                container.getContainerProperties().setIdleBetweenPolls(5_000L);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Or, configure your own factory rather than using Boot's auto-configured factory.

Comment: I did try this before I asked, actually. However it would not work, at the time this injection happens, the Listener has been constructed with a copy of ContainerProperties.
Getting back the container and setting the ContainerProperties would not affect the copied ContainerProperties that it holds.

Comment: That is true if you change it after the container is started but if you do it the way I suggested, it will work.