# Kafka listeners with different retry attempts

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-retry

I have three spring `@KafkaListener`s, all consuming from the **same** topic, but I need to have different retry attempts for each listener which results in having different RetryPolicy I guess.

I am on version `2.7.11` right now; Should I define three different listener container Factories as well or there is a way to handle them on the same listener container factory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RetryTemplate` in the container factory is deprecated now that error handlers support backoffs and exception classification.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1886

You can add a container customizer to the factory and set a different error handler (with different back offs) for each container.

Comment: Could you please clarify on the difference between factory and container? I have a `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` in our kafka library and created another in the application myself. I created a customizer like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62456540/when-using-kafkalistener-in-springboot-how-to-set-idlebetweenpolls and I get the error that there are two factories. How I configure two containers within a factory?

Comment: The factory creates a container for each of its listeners. If you have two or more factories; there are several solutions; you can mark one of them as `@Primary`; you can change the constructor parameter name to match the bean name of one of your factories; you can change the constructor to receive a `List` of factories to get them all.